# iOS: XMPP: Message Archiving for Group Chat Message

Tags: ios, xmpp, message, xmppframework, archiving

All one-one chat is send with Message Type as Chat.
Thus the Message Archiving technique (shown below) worked fine for me to save/retrieve chat history.

```
// Setup message archiving
xmppMessageArchivingStorage = [XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];
xmppMessageArchiving = [[XMPPMessageArchiving alloc] initWithMessageArchivingStorage:xmppMessageArchivingStorage];
[xmppMessageArchiving setClientSideMessageArchivingOnly:YES];

// Activate xmpp modules
[xmppMessageArchiving   activate:xmppStream];
// Add delegate
[xmppMessageArchiving  addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

---

However for Group Chat, the message type sent is "groupchat"
This will not be archived by the XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage

---

Can someone please guide me as to how I can achieve the Message Archiving for Group Chat Message.

Comment: Y you need archive room messages.If u joined a new room , u can get all messages already there in that room

Comment: But I would want all messages saved even after I have joined it. So that I can show all messages right from the archive.

Comment: if you any sample code or project to get chat history from ejbberd server in iOS swift.

Answer (score 2):

This is the Series of Stanza that you will need to send to get Archived Messages. For more detail you can checkout http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html

REQ

```
<iq type='get' id='mrug_sender@staging.openfire.com'>
       <list xmlns='urn:xmpp:archive'
               with='mrug_target_155@staging.openfire.com'>
        <set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>
            <max>6900</max>
        </set>
      </list>
   </iq>
```

RES

```
<iq type="result" id="mrug_sender@staging.openfire.com" to="mrug_sender@staging.openfire.com/Psi">
<list xmlns="urn:xmpp:archive">
<chat with="mrug_target_155@staging.openfire.com" start="2014-06-07T06:52:26.041Z"/>
<chat with="mrug_target_155@staging.openfire.com" start="2014-06-07T07:06:53.372Z"/>
<set xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm">
<first index="0">866</first>
<last>867</last>
<count>2</count>
</set>
</list>
</iq>
```

REQ

```
<iq type='get' id='mrug_sender@staging.openfire.com'>
    <retrieve xmlns='urn:xmpp:archive'  with='mrug_target_155@staging.openfire.com'  start='2014-06-07T06:52:26.041Z'>
     <set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>
       <max>8000</max>
     </set>
    </retrieve>
 </iq>
```

RES

```
 <iq type="result" id="mrug_sender@staging.openfire.com" to="mrug_sender@staging.openfire.com/Psi">
    <chat xmlns="urn:xmpp:archive" with="mrug_target_155@staging.openfire.com" start="2014-06-07T06:52:26.041Z">
    <from secs="0" jid="mrug_target_155@staging.openfire.com">
    <body>Wow !! This is Archived Message</body>
    </from>
    <set xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm">
    <first index="0">0</first>
    <last>0</last>
    <count>1</count>
    </set>
    </chat>
    </iq>
```

To Fetch List of all Conversations

```
<iq type='get' id='mrug_sender@staging.openfire.com'>
       <list xmlns='urn:xmpp:archive'>
        <set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>
            <max>6900</max>
        </set>
      </list>
</iq>
```

Comment: Hello @Mrug, I used https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework. I don't know how to store these retrieved messages please help me with this.

Comment: Just follow the above series of Stanza you will get the response in XML, which you will need to parse and store either in SQLite or Coredata.

Comment: I used XMPPFramework and this framework automatically stores the messages and I want to store these archived messages with coredata database which is created by XMPPFramework so the problem is I am not able to store these messages @Mrug

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get archive messages from xmpp core database. Use Below code.

```
XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage *_xmppMsgStorage = [XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [_xmppMsgStorage mainThreadManagedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject"
                                                     inManagedObjectContext:moc];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];
//[request setFetchLimit:20];

NSError *error;
NSString *predicateFrmt = @"bareJidStr == %@";

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateFrmt, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",GroupName,GROUP_CHAT_DOMAIN]];
request.predicate = predicate;
NSArray *messages = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```