# Get Chat history in between two users from XMPP

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xmpp, openfire

In my application i need to get the **Chat History**.

In my app Chatting is working perfectly. in between two user and group chat also.

But I need to get **old Messages** from **OpenFire** using **XMPP** and for that i tried below links but not successful.

[XMPPFramework - Retrieving Openfire Message Archives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173251/retrieving-open-fire-message-archive-using-xmppframework-in-ios?rq=1)

[XMPPFramework - Unable to Retrieve Chat History from Openfire Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171777/unable-to-get-chat-history-from-openfire-server-in-ios)

[XMPPFramework - Retrieve Archived Messages From Openfire Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397172/xmpp-retrieve-archive-messages-from-openfire-server)

Don't know how to fetch the old messages from Openfire using XMPP in ios.
So, Any link, idea or code will be great Help.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: hello @sam 
can you tell me about group chat ?

Comment: I am working on group chat using xmpp framework and already implemented  but last group which is created by me or other user can't be a active, i mean i can't send message on previously joined group i have to join and active that group at all time ,
can you tell me what's perfect solution for this ..?