# feature not implemented while retrieving archive message

Tags: xmpp, openfire

i am using `Openfire 3.8.2` and have installed monitor plugin and enable the archiving for one to one chat.

now i am able to view the archive chat on the server side but when i pass a stanza i am getting `feature not implemented`

**Request**

```
<iq type='get' id='334'>
  <list xmlns='urn:xmpp:archive'
        with='user4@mydomain.com'>
    <set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>
      <max>30</max>
    </set>
  </list>
</iq>
```

**Response**

```
<iq type="error" id="334" to="user1@mydomain.com/458">
<error type="cancel" code="501">
<feature-not-implemented xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
</error>
</iq>
```

can anyone tell me what i am missing here ? i have explored all the threads on stackoverflow but didn't find any solution there.

i have set the following properties in openfire system properties but still not getting same error

```
conversation.idleTime   10

conversation.maxAge 0

conversation.maxRetrievable 100

conversation.maxTime    60

conversation.messageArchiving   true

conversation.metadataArchiving  true

conversation.roomArchiving  true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it was just a small mistake in sending stanza , i missed the `namespace` attribute in `max` tag , following is the correct stanza

```
<iq type='get' id='334'>
  <list xmlns='urn:xmpp:archive'
        with='user4@mydomain.com'>
    <set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>
      <max xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>30</max>
    </set>
  </list>
</iq>
```

Comment: I tried this. But no luck. It is still throwing me 501 error whenever I use urn:xmpp:archive. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hunt, I reinstalled that monitoring plugin. It is working now. Thanks for the quick reply :)

Comment: Its not working with MUCLight as well, even trying this max xmls ssuggestion, Example 5,6 Section 2.2 XEP 0059