# OpenFire + FastPath WebChat - Pre Fill the User Chat Window with ongoing Conversation

Tags: xmpp, openfire, livechat

Currently I am using [Olark](http://olark.com) for live chat on my website.
I am planning to replace it with an in house OpenFire installation.
However, there is one problem.

With Olark live chat snippet (which I embed on my website) - if a user opens the website in multiple tabs - it's prefilled with the ongoing conversation. For e.g. - you can try it on ([moonclerk.com](http://moonclerk.com)).

How do I achieve the same pre population of chat window with the ongoing conversation with OpenFire + FP WebChat?

Answer (score 2):

The way we achieve it at Olark is not exactly trivial. We don't actually use an XMPP client on the end-user's side, which makes it a bit easier, but basically our transport layer is able to grab conversation events for a conversation in-progress based on a session UUID that is stored in the user's cookies. XMPP isn't involved in that process at all, for us (it is only concerned with final delivery to and from Operators).

I don't know what FastPath's architecture is like, but if you were looking for this functionality, or to add it yourself, XMPP supports retrieving some n number of messages from the message history for a client. Check out [XMPPFramework - Retrieve Archived Messages From Openfire Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397172/xmpp-retrieve-archive-messages-from-openfire-server) for more on that.