# XMPP connection closes on sending IQ Smack 4.1

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I am developing an android application using smack 4.1

When I send IQ packet to server, the connection to server(openfire) gets closed.

here is the packet I am sending to server.
`<iq id='pk1' type='get'><list xmlns='urn:xmpp:archive' with='ahmed@domain'<set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'><max>10</max></set></list></iq>`

I have tested it with both `sendStanza(stanza);` and `sendIqWithResponseCallback(IQ, StanzaListener, ExceptionCallback, timeout);`

This is what I am trying to achieve [xmppframework-retrieve-archived-messages-from-openfire-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397172/xmppframework-retrieve-archived-messages-from-openfire-server)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will find the reason why Openfire closes the connection in Openfire's logs.

Comment: @Flow thanks man, the issue was with the XML. I had to use `rightAngleBracket();` before adding child element "set".