# Getting error while fetching archived messages(XEP-0313 MAM - chat history) from openfire-4.1.1

Tags: android, openfire, smack

Openfire version - 4.1.1(Which has XEP-0313 MAM support)
Smack version - 4.2.0-rc2-SNAPSHOT(Which has XEP-0313 MAM support)
Monitoring Service version - 1.5.4

After installing Monitoring Service plugin in Openfire, I've also eabled Message Archiving.

To fetch archived messages,

```
    MamManager mamManager = MamManager.getInstanceFor(mConnection);
    MamQueryResult mamQueryResult = mamManager.queryArchive(5);
```

Sent Stanza :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <iq id="33F2H-15" type="set">
    <query
    xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:1" queryid="f18e30a5-f70c-47a3-9c01-131b6936a780">
    <set
    xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm">
    <max>5</max>
    </set>
    </query>
    </iq>
```

Received Stanza :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <iq type="error" id="33F2H-15" to="abc@192.168.2.128/9jifslkilf">
    <query xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:1" queryid="f18e30a5-f70c-47a3-9c01-131b6936a780">
    <set xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm">
    <max>5</max>
    </set>
    </query>
    <error code="503" type="cancel">
    <service-unavailable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas" />
    </error>
    </iq>
```

Questions :

- Why there is an error of 503 - cancel - service-unavailable?
- Is openfire server congfigured properly for MAM - XEP-0313 support,
  or am I missing something?
- Is this an issue of smack(MamManager)?

May be it's possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35935397/get-xmpp-chat-history-openfire), but that doesn't help much.

Comment: As per monitoring plugin XEP-0313 support, it's expecting xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:0", however you are sending xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:1".

Comment: did you find the solution?