# Retrieve Message Archive - XMPPFramework iOS

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I am developing ios messaging app and I used [XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework).

This XMPPFramework supports XEP-0313 [Message Archive Management](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/blob/master/Extensions/XEP-0313/XMPPMessageArchiveManagement.m).

I have enabled Monitoring Service on openfire and it's archiving messages.

I want to retrieve archived messages from the server to iOS app. I researched on google and StackOverflow but nothing found helpfull resources regarding how to retrieve archived messages and save it to the core data(Used by XMPPFramework by default).

I know about this StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397172/xmppframework-retrieve-archived-messages-from-openfire-server/20045656) it shows me how to retrieve the messages via IQ stanza from the XMPP but I want to retrieve messages directly via this XMPPFramework which already supports but I don't know how to implement? I want to retrieve all conversation which happened after particular date between two users.

Any help will be highly appreciated thank you in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it is not late answering as I had the same issue. 
First have a look at the :https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html#entities
You have xml examples, and you need to implement the XMPPFramework to build such messages. Here is my example:

```
let query = DDXMLElement.init(name: "query", xmlns: "urn:xmpp:mam:2")

let x = DDXMLElement.init(name: "x", xmlns: "jabber:x:data")
x.addAttribute(withName: "type", stringValue: "submit")


let f1 = DDXMLElement.init(name: "field")
f1.addAttribute(withName: "var", stringValue: "FORM_TYPE")
f1.addAttribute(withName: "type", stringValue: "hidden")
let f1value = DDXMLElement.init(name: "value")
f1value.stringValue = "urn:xmpp:mam:2"

let f2 = DDXMLElement.init(name: "field")
f2.addAttribute(withName: "var", stringValue: "start")

let f2value = DDXMLElement.init(name: "value")
f2value.stringValue = "2010-06-07T00:00:00Z"

f1.addChild(f1value)
f2.addChild(f2value)
x.addChild(f2)
x.addChild(f1)
query.addChild(x)

let iq :XMPPIQ = XMPPIQ(iqType: XMPPIQ.IQType.set, to: someJID, elementID: "someId", child: query)
 print(iq)
self.xmppController?.xmppStream.send(iq)
```